# how to check if a list is a consecutive number in python?

Tags: python, sequence

How to write python code that let the computer know if the list is a right sequence and the position doesn't matter, it will return true, otherwise it return false.
below are some of my example, I really don't know how to start

```
b=[1,2,3,4,5] #return true
b=[1,2,2,1,3] # return false
b=[2,3,1,5,4] #return true
b=[2,4,6,4,3] # return false
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing the sorted list against the range? `sorted(b)==list(range(min(b), max(b)+1)))`

Comment: I just try it, thx a lot, and it works.

Comment: do you know how to check if there is only have one group of duplicate number and that dupicate number are  only double in a list?

Comment: if you `sort` values then `"sequence"` means that `b[1] - b[0] == 1` and `b[2] - b[1] == 1`,...`b[n+1] - b[n] == 1` and you could use this to check your data (if you don't know other methods).

Answer (score 1):

sort function is O(nlogn), we can use for loop which is O(n):

```
def check_seq(in_list):
    now_ele = set()
    min_ele = max_ele = in_list[0]

    for i in in_list:
        if i in now_ele:
            return False
        min_ele = min(i, min_ele)
        max_ele = max(i, max_ele)
        now_ele.add(i)
    
    if max_ele-min_ele+1 == len(in_list):
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: our teacher only allow us to us one one line to check, I have already solve the problem, thx for your coding

Answer (score 1):

Create a set and one to compare with -- based on minimum and maximum:

```
isRightSequence = set(range(min(b), max(b)+1)) == set(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite simple and can be solved a few ways.

1. The conditional approach - if there is a number that is bigger than the length of the list, it automatically cannot be a sequence because there can only be numbers from 1-n where n is the size of the list. Also, you have to check if there are any duplicates in the list as this cannot be possible either. If none of these conditions occur, it should return true
2. Using dictionary - go through the entire list and add it as a key to a dictionary. Afterwards, simply loop through numbers 1-n where n is the length of the list and check if they are keys in the dictionary, if one of them isn't, return false. If all of them are, return true.

Both of these are quite simply approaches and you should be able to implement them yourselves. However, this is one implementation for both.

1.

```
def solve(list1):
    seen = {}
    for i in list1:
        if i > len(list1):
            return False
        if i in seen:
            return False
        seen[i] = True
    return False
```

2. 

```
def solve(list1):
    seen = {}
    for i in list1:
        seen[i] = True
    for i in range (1, len(list1)+1):
        if i not in seen:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution needs O(n) runtime and O(n) space

```py
def is_consecutive(l: list[int]):
    if not l: 
        return False
    low = min(l)
    high = max(l)
    # Bounds Check
    if high - low != len(l) - 1:
        return False
    
    # Test all indices exist
    test_vec = [False] * len(l) # O(n)
    for i in range(len(l)): 
        test_vec[l[i] - low] = True
    return all(test_vec)

assert is_consecutive(range(10))
assert is_consecutive([-1, 1,0])
assert not is_consecutive([1,1])
assert not is_consecutive([1,2,4,6,5])
```